# How to create a statement that will print out words that start with particular word?

Tags: python, string, python-3.x

How to print words starting from a particular letter in python without using functions, but using methods or loops.

1 ) I got a string and wants to print words starting with  'm'

```
St= "where is my mobile"
```

> result =  "my", "mobile"

2 ) For the below list, how to output list starting with "p", which  can be either lower or upper.

```
List = ['mobile',"pencil","Pen","eraser","Book"]
 
 RESULT= "pencil","pen".
```

Thanks

Nb: This is not a homework, only a python newbie

Comment: What did you tried? Show us the code!

Comment: It looks like you want us to write some code for you. While many users are willing to produce code for a coder in distress, they usually only help when the poster has already tried to solve the problem on his own. A good way to show this effort is to include the code you've written so far, example input (if there is any), the expected output, and the output you actually get (console output, tracebacks, etc.). The more detail you provide, the more answers you are likely to receive. Check the [FAQ](http://stackoverflow.com/tour) and [How to Ask](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask).

Comment: @Poshi , I tried but couldnt past two or three lines and not working for me

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Use `str.startswith`

**Ex:**

```
St= "where is my mobile"
for i in St.split():
    if i.startswith("m"):
        print(i)
```

**Output:**

```
my
mobile
```

Using `filter`

**Ex:**

```
L = ['mobile',"pencil","Pen","eraser","Book"]
print( list(filter(lambda x: x.lower().startswith("p"), L)) )
```

**Output:**

```
['pencil', 'Pen']
```

Comment: okay . i was trying to create a variable using startswith and split methods and trying to print it ..but it didnt  worked for me..  this is fine .. thank you

Comment: You are welcome :)

Answer (score 3):

Try this code:

```
#String to be splitted
St = 'where is my mobile'

#Split the string on blank characters
List = St.split()

#for each element in the list, if it starts with 'm' then print it
for s in List:
    if s.startswith('m'):
        print(s)
```

Comment: thanks luca. well done.. .i found where i went wrong.